# How to sort diferent type of lists with template in C++

Tags: c++, list, class, sorting, templates

In my homework my task is to create the FooCl class for these:

```
    double d[] = {1.3, 0.7, 2.4, 1.5, 6.2, 5.7, 8.6, 9.1};
    FooCl<double> itemsD(d, sizeof(d) / sizeof(d[0]));

    std::string s[] = {"C++", "Haskell", "Python", "Java"};
    FooCl<std::string> itemsS(s, sizeof(s) / sizeof(s[0]));

    itemsD.mySort();
    itemsS.mySort();
```

I made a constructor/destructor for it, but I don't know how to create two different functions with templates for the two different types of lists.
I think I would need to use some kind of overloading but don't know how.

```
template <typename T>
class FooCl
{
private:
    T *mItems;
    int mItemsSize;

public:
    FooCl(T items[], int itemsSize)
    {
        mItems = new T[itemsSize];
        for (int i=0; i<itemsSize; ++i)
        {
            this->mItems[i] = items[i];
        }
        this->mItemsSize = itemsSize;
    };

    ~FooCl()
    {
        delete[] mItems;
    }

    void mySort()
    {
        //I have no idea how to write this function, so it can sort two different types of lists.
    }
};
```

Comment: Why not use `std::sort`?

Comment: At least take a look at `std::sort`, you will find `std::less`, for example.

Comment: You don't need to write special code for specific types - the element type is `T`, the template parameter. I suspect that you have kind of missed the point of templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) as shown below:

```
void mySort()
{
//--vvvvvvvvv------------------------------------>use std::sort
    std::sort(mItems, mItems + mItemsSize);
}
```

You can even write your sort functionality/implementation which will include the use of `mItems` and `mItemsSize`.

Comment: I doubt the homework is to just call `std::sort`. The instructor probably wants them to write their own sort algorithm.

Comment: @Caleth I have added a note saying that it is also possible to write your own sort using `mItems` and `mItemsSize` if it is really the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort any container like `std::array` or `std::vector`

```
template <typename Container, typename Func>
void sort(Container& c, Func functor)
{
    std::sort(std::begin(c), std::end(c), functor);
}
```

usage

```
std::vector<int> vct {1,2,3,1,2};
sort(vct, [](const int lhs, const int rhs) {return lhs > rhs;});
```

Answer (score 1):

The two operations important for sorting is comparison and swapping.

Both `double` and `std::string` already have definitions for `<`, which is the idiomatic comparison operator.

There is already a template `std::swap`, which is the idiomatic swap function.

You need to write a sort that uses `mItems` and `mItemsSize`, comparing items (with `<`) and swapping those that are in the wrong position (with `std::swap`).